# Storyboard has become unstable. Compiles but sometimes Auto Layout goes crazy

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard

I have a strange issue with storyboard, it has become unstable. 
When I'm working and compile, sometimes I go this screen and see something like this:

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

But the most strange thing, is most of the times It don't get fixed doing any change. The only thing I have to do is to go to storyboard, and then I don't know why, the project recompile storyboard again (which take ages...) and when it's recompiled and I go to the same screen it's displayed correctly again. 
It makes me loose some time and it's very annoying, as I need to recompile storyboard again when I have this issue. 
Does anyone can throw any light on how to fix this or what the source of the issue can be?

Comment: i can guess 2 things, either you are using size class and designing in a fixed size IB or you have not set all required constraints to the elements of the controller.

Comment: what is "fixed size"? You mean when I set the property of a window to iphone 6s size or freeform instead of inferred???? This is what is causing my problem?

Comment: i think so...not sure..but happened something like this with me long time ago..

Comment: It's incredible. It has fixed my problem!!!! I can't figure out how you managed to find the solution of such a strange issue, but if you post it I will accept it as valid solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is coming because i think you are using size classes and designing your controllers in the storyboard by giving it as a fixed device size. Either change the controller size to inferred, or disable size classes.